# SQL Server How to prevent sql injection in dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

I have an ASP.Net MVC application which use SQL 2012 as the database server.
I have used Views,Stored Procedures (With/Without dynamic sql queries). I 've heard that dynamic sql can be a victim of sql injection.

Here is one of my sample dynamic query..

```
DECLARE @Username AS Varchar(100);
DECLARE @Password AS Varchar(100);

SET @Username = 'user1';
SET @Password = '123';

DECLARE @Query AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE Username ='+ @Username+ ' AND Password = '+@Password+';

EXEC(@Query)
```

How can I write this query preventing sql injection?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection.aspx

Comment: Kudos to you for taking the time to make this right!!! Far too many people just blindly toss that kind of code into production and their site gets hijacked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The premise is essentially the same in SQL as it is in application code... Never directly concatenate input *as code* but instead treat it as a parameter.  So if your query is something like this:

```
SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password';
```

Then you can execute it with parameters using `sp_executesql`:

```
exec sp_executesql @Query, N'@Username varchar(100), @Password varchar(100)', @Username, @Password
```